# Cassandra JMX MBin to monitor number of active/idle connection from tomcat

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-0.7

I am using Tomcat and Cassandra. I am trying to write JMX shell script to find out following

> 05/12/2013 13:37:16 -0400 org.archive.jmx.Client numActive: 0
>   05/12/2013 13:37:16 -0400 org.archive.jmx.Client numIdle: 4

Please note: I used this format to manage database connection pooling using Tomcat and Oracle. I want similar in Cassandra.

When I run my JMX client on tomcat server (which runs on 8003 port) then I see number of following related MBins as given below.

```
me.prettyprint.cassandra.service:name=perf4j,type=perf4j
me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_NexText:MonitorType=hector,ServiceType=nextext
```

I am looking for which MBin I should use to monitor connection of Cassandra from tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some analysis and I found that I should use following

> **Bean Name:**
>   me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_NexText:MonitorType=hector,ServiceType=nextext
>
> - Property type:
> - NumActive
> - NumBlockedThreads
> - NumPools
> - NumExhaustedPools